# Weird blue and purple humanoid superhero keychain with "Z" chest emblem, X-eyes, and trident head

Tags: character-identification, super-hero, toys

I have this weird rubber keychain. It’s from America. I obtained it around 2008. It’s kind of bendy, but bounces back to normal when you stop. Who made it, and what is this character called?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there any maker's marks on the plastic?

Comment: @Valorum There are none whatsoever.

Comment: A reverse image search with Google didn’t find anything relevant.

Comment: Some cursory searching initially led me to post an answer that this might be a really crude [Beerus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beerus) but I've since changed my mind and deleted the answer

Comment: Definitely not Beerus. Not a terrible idea, though.

Comment: My impulse with the X eyes and a Z logo is something with zombies, but I can't find anything.

Comment: I feel like it might be Uglydoll related what with the weird x eyes, but can’t find anything about rubber superhero keychains from that company.

Comment: The Watch Over Voodoo dolls have some similar "superhero" designs, but in yarn, and not quite matching.

Comment: Purple and blue suit made me think of Galactus; http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lQblDbIbiU4/TdGiLzElaYI/AAAAAAAABv8/Xhn_TntLMlk/s1600/FF%2B243%2Bgalactus%2Btired.jpg

Comment: Where did you obtain it?  Could it be marketing from a local business?  (though I'd expect a marketing thing to have included the full name of the company or contact information)

Comment: @Valorum But no Z on chest...

Comment: @Valorum: In that same vein, also looks like it could be a cutesy-fied version of Ziran the Tester who also doesn't have a Z on their chest (that I could find anyway) but their name does begin with Z.

Comment: @LAK I have no idea where I obtained it, other than that I am pretty sure it was in America.

Comment: I came across a children's book character which reminded me of this, although it's not perfect match: Zloukch https://www.amazon.com/Zachary-son-Zloukch-Flipattes-conteurs/dp/2895404186

Comment: [I’m offering 100 or more reputation in a bounty](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12518/102999) for this question if I get a good answer. Valorum is offering an extra 500 reputation, which is awesome.

Comment: wild speculating: A blue cat, a sidekick of the main character, not regularly dressing a superhero suit. Maybe three horns, or two ears and one horn. Blue could be the normal color, and Z is the name of itself or the main character. The heart made me think about "fall in love" the eyes and mouth can underline the "not sane" part of this emotional condition. In this case Z is the name of the beloved of course.

Comment: It could already be a fork...

Comment: Was it being sold as brand new or second hand? My gut feeling is that it's possibly a Japanese series based on the styling of the eyes

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I’d assume new, but I really don’t know how I got it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After scouring the internet and coming up with nothing, I finally found the answer in the most unlikeliest of places: my aunt’s house.  There, by complete coincidence, I saw this keychain:

[image]

My aunt says it’s from a pencil case she bought at Borders books, a pencil case like this:

[image]

Which has this keychain:

[image]

Look a little familiar?

Thanks to this, I was able to find that the brand is [Pet Champz](https://printpattern.blogspot.com/2009/07/paperchase-pet-champz.html).

Comment: You found it!!!!

Comment: And the delicious bounty shall be yours!

Comment: It could have been _my_ aunt's house, but _noooooo_... :) I'm kidding! Well done, Laurel!

Comment: Oh Paperchase! I remember that place :-)

Comment: @Valorum - The delicious _bounties_! :)

Comment: It looks like 9 characters, one for each letter of "Pet Champz" (one of the characters having a mirrored P to distinguish from the other P).

Answer (score 2):

The coloring and the shape of the helmet are reminiscent of the Marvel character [Galactus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus). (Although the logo on its chest and the cape don't match up so well.)

[image]

Comment: There's some similarity (three-pronged helmet thingie, blue and purple colour theme) but not enough that it's likely to be him unless it's an insane Russian knock-off

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, probably true. My thought was that there have been enough alternate universes, variant models, character redesigns, etc. that there *might* have once been some incarnation of Galactus that looked closer to that. But I agree it's unlikely.

Comment: If one search for "cute galactus" or "little galactus" one can find a horrible lot of pictures ^^ my favorites: minion-galactus and my-little-pony-galactus ... but sadly no rubber-galactus

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Galactus_(Earth-91126) says: "Trivia: Although he was eaten by the zombies of Earth-Z, his flesh didn't imbue them with the Power Cosmic,unlike his Earth-2149 conterpart." Could explain the Heart with "Z" and the zombie-eyes. And "First appearance: Marvel Zombies Return  #5
(November, 2009)" could match the time around 2008

Answer (score -1):

It is a try...

[image: Pete the Cat]
[image]

I do not know the cartoon, but the books came in 2008 and maybe there is somewhere in it a scene "Pete the Cat as Hero for Love"

I think the form of the head is similar, it has the heart on his chest (but without the "Z") and it has this look, not far away from xx-eyes.

Comment: This is probably the closest guess yet but it still doesn't really look that much like the keychain.

Comment: Yes I know, I hope it is not a little store-merchandise junk and someone can solve this puzzling question... I am curious now!

Comment: Definitely not correct, but good guess.

Answer (score -3):

I spotted a character that may have inspired the keychain:  [Midna](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Midna), the titular princess in "The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess."

[image: Twilight Princess]

The game was released in 2006, which fits the time period.  If this is the origin of the keychain, it was surely an unlicensed knock-off product, meant to evoke the Midna character without actually infringing on Nintendo's intellectual property.  There are clear differences between the two characters; however, the "Z" on the chest may be an addition allusion to the "Zelda" series.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The keychain has an anchor head with three prongs, and the Fused Shadows that Midna wears has either two of four prongs, never three. The Z is just a coincidence, as it's in a heart, which is not a Zelda symbol, a triangle is.

Comment: This doesn't look anything like the keychain :-)