# What character is this on the back of Reese's Puffs?

Tags: character-identification, advertisements

What character is this on the back of Reese's Puffs cereal?

It seems to be some weird mutant Mickey Mouse.

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about science fiction of fantasy.

Comment: @user14111 it seems to be a fantastical cartoon character that I did not recognize. There are many such questions on this site.

Comment: @user14111 see for example here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212627/weird-blue-and-purple-humanoid-superhero-keychain-with-z-chest-emblem-x-eyes/

Comment: @Valorum no. Simply thought I did already. Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [KAWS' Companion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaws#Artworks)

> Kaws' *Companion* is a grayscale clown-like figure based on Mickey Mouse with his face obscured by both hands, and two bones sticking out of his head.

The box is part of a series of [co-branded artwork](https://www.lifestyleasia.com/sg/food-drink/dining/kaws-wants-to-take-over-your-breakfast-next-with-a-reeses-puffs-collaboration/) collaborations

> *The co-branded KAWS Reese’s Puffs cereal boxes will see his signature double “XX” symbol sit right above the Reese’s Puffs branding. Even the KAWS companion couldn’t resist taking [a dip in the bowl of cereal](https://twitter.com/saint/status/1447869792308940801/photo/1). At the back, another companion covers his eyes as he stands under a glorious Reese’s Puffs storm.*
>
> <sub><sup>[KAWS wants to take over your breakfast next with a Reese’s Puffs collab](https://www.lifestyleasia.com/sg/food-drink/dining/kaws-wants-to-take-over-your-breakfast-next-with-a-reeses-puffs-collaboration/)</sup></sub>